# EntityFrameworkCore: DeleteBehavior too many options

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Setting up the builder parameter inside the OnModelCreating method in my app DbContext I found many options in OnDelete/DeleteBehavior: Cascade, ClientCascade, ClientNoAction, ClientSetNull, NoAction, Restrict and SetNull.

[image]

Searching on the web I found some content about some of them, but not about them all. What are the differences about them?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the active ones can be referred from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) and a [more nourished documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-3.1).

- Cascade is literally what it means, child and dependants are dropped.
- ClientCascade basically drops dependant entities as well.
- ClientNoAction basically does nothing to any foreign keys, they are intact even after deletion. ***Not recommended by Microsoft.***
- NoAction is basically nothing, the entity itself is the only one affected.
- Restrict is the same as NoAction
- SetNull basically sets relationship keys to null

Comment: NoAction and Restrict set foreign keys to null as well as SetNull

Answer (score 0):

doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-5.0

According to my understanding,
Recommended use:

- Cascade: Cascade delete and set up DB.
- ClientCascade: Cascade delete and not set up DB.
- SetNull: Set FK to NULL, and set up DB.
- ClientSetNull: Set FK to NULL, and not set up DB.